# Dockerfile -Error: lsstat target/springbootdemo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar: no such file or directory

Tags: docker, openshift, dockerfile, openshift-enterprise, openshift-3

I have a spring boot project and trying to build the project with a Docker file on OpenShift V3.

The problem is that I only have my source code in my git repo; no target directory or jar file. My Dockerfile is not able to get the final artifact (packaging the application to a jar).

Following is my docker file contents

```
FROM bdf/api-java8-maven-exp-srv-builder
EXPOSE 8080
VOLUME /tmp
WORKDIR /code
ADD pom.xml /code/pom.xml
ADD Dockerfile /code  
RUN ["mvn", "dependency:resolve"]  
RUN ["mvn", "verify"]

ADD src /code/src  
RUN ["mvn", "package"]
ADD /code/target/springbootdemo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar
RUN bash -c 'touch /app.jar'
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-Dspring.profiles.active=container","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

All commands are working properly except ADD /code/target/springbootdemo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar

Command:  RUN ["mvn", "package"]  - It execute successfully and shows that jar file is created on console at location /target/springbootdemo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

*Projct Folder Structure

```
Project Name- 
 - src Folder 
 - mvn/wrapper
 - Docker File 
 - Pom.XML
 - mvnw
 - mvnwc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following DockerFile works for me

```
FROM bfg/api-java8-maven-exp-srv-builder
EXPOSE 8080

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
ONBUILD ADD . /usr/src/app
ONBUILD RUN mvn install
ONBUILD ADD /usr/src/app/target/springbootdemo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar

CMD ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```